# Convection in standing fluid

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to know if convection occurs, and contributes significantly to evaporation, in a puddle of water at room temperature, on a level floor. Do currents develop in the water as evaporation takes place? And what if the water was initially at a higher temperature? Would there be convection, and would it contribute significantly to the cooling of the water?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In my judgment, convection within the liquid water would not contribute significantly.  However, convection in the air due to wind would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first pass, we could look at whether [convection cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93B%C3%A9nard_convection) are predicted to form in the puddle.

Evaporation cools surfaces, where latent heat is being removed. This results in a temperature gradient from the cooler surface to warmer depths. There is then a corresponding driving force for the warmer (i.e., less dense) lower liquid to rise. At some point, this tendency overcomes the viscosity, and liquid exchange essentially switches on, shifting cooler (warmer) water downward (upward):

[image]

Examples at different scales:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The threshold for convection cell generation of this type is a [Rayleigh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number) of greater than approximately 1000. (The Rayleigh number dimensionlessly compares gravitational and viscous effects.) Plugging in the material constants of water around room temperature, I find that this threshold lies between 1 mm and 1 cm puddle height for a temperature difference of 1°C, for example. This could help you estimate whether currents exist in the puddle as it dries through evaporation.

It's difficult to give a more precise answer or to address your other questions because you don't specify the humidity, wind speed, evaporation rate, puddle dimensions, or surrounding material. Once you know the humidity and wind speed, you can estimate the evaporation rate. Once you have that, you can estimate the heat flux from the latent heat and mass transfer. Once you have that, you can estimate the relative contributions of convection and conduction within the puddle.